# Does SQLite support referential integrity?

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite, referential-integrity

I have a Django web-server configured to use SQLite.

In a many-to-many relationship (with extra fields), Django forces me to use the relationship model to establish a relationship between two objects. But I'm able to create a relationship between objects, that don't yet exist in the related tables.

For e.g:

```
I have table1 and table2 which are related via table12.
In table1, there is just one object called A.
In table2, there is just one object called X.
I can create a record in table12 that depict a relationship between A & Y; even though Y doesn't exist in table2.
```

My relationship model has marked the foreign keys appropriately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQLite does not enforce [foreign key constraints](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) by default (mostly to be backward compatible).

To enable it, you have to execute

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1
```

after you connected to the database.

See the manual about [`PRAGMA foreign_keys`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) for more details.

Comment: Also found a way to enable it in Django! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745763/enable-integrity-checking-with-sqlite-in-django

Comment: A slightly nicer variant would be `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON` rather than `1`