# Heroku Rails db migration file order and relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, dbmigrate

I have a `User` model and a `Role` model. When I started building the app, I start by creating the `User` model and the migration file that was generated contain a reference to Roles:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :password_digest
      t.boolean :banned
      t.references :role, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then I created the `Role` model which generated this migration file:

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :access_level

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to deploy to Heroku and migrating my database per the documentation using the following command `heroku run rails db:migrate` (using Rails 5).

I am getting an error from Heroku saying:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ gentle-headland-79177... up, run.9293 (Free)
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.131367 #4] DEBUG -- :    (90.7ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying PRIMARY KEY)
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.152682 #4] DEBUG -- :    (11.5ms)  CREATE TABLE "ar_internal_metadata" ("key" character varying PRIMARY KEY, "value" character varying, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.155373 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(6845940114126317925);
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.172106 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
I, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.178453 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateUsers (20161117083901)
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.181903 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  BEGIN
== 20161117083901 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.199351 #4] DEBUG -- :    (13.4ms)  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "first_name" character varying, "last_name" character varying, "username" character varying, "email" character varying, "password" character varying, "password_digest" character varying, "banned" boolean, "role_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_642f17018b"
FOREIGN KEY ("role_id")
  REFERENCES "roles" ("id")
)
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.200707 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-12-31T08:15:33.202190 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.2ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(6845940114126317925)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "roles" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "first_name" character varying, "last_name" character varying, "username" character varying, "email" character varying, "password" character varying, "password_digest" character varying, "banned" boolean, "role_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_642f17018b"
FOREIGN KEY ("role_id")
  REFERENCES "roles" ("id")
)
```

From my understanding, it appears Heroku is expecting `Role` to be defined first then `User`.

Why is it on my local machine, I can do db:migrate fine but on Heroku it fails?

Difference between Sqlite3 and Postgresql perhaps?

How do I go about solving this deployment problem?

Do I just rename my create_role migration file to have an earlier timestamp than the create_user migration file? Is that even recommended practice ? :D

### Update

I did a git clone of my repository to a Desktop folder on my iMac.

Then I ran `rails db:migrate` on that new local copy.

No error whatsoever. All db migrations ran, all the tables are in place along with all the relationships. Something's really messed up on the Heroku end.

### Update 2

Did another checkout of my repository into a new Desktop folder, ran `bundle install` and then tried this version of the db:migrate command:

`rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

and I see the same error output about roles does not exists

HOWEVER

I then created a brand spanking new rails project `honey`:

```
rails new honey
```

Did `bundle install`

Then went:

```
rails generate model User name:string role:references
```

Finally, I went:

```
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

and no errors...

I've clearly have not generated any `Role` model, so why does it not fail?

Here's the console log:

```
Warlocks-iMac:bad clementwu$ cd honey/
Warlocks-iMac:honey clementwu$ ls
Gemfile      Rakefile     config       lib          test
Gemfile.lock app          config.ru    log          tmp
README.md    bin          db           public       vendor
Warlocks-iMac:honey clementwu$ rails generate model User name:string role:references
Running via Spring preloader in process 27200
Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20170101100613_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/user_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/users.yml
Warlocks-iMac:honey clementwu$ rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
== 20170101100613 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0018s
== 20170101100613 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0018s) =============================

Warlocks-iMac:honey clementwu$
```

[image: screenshot]

The database is created and even shows the `role_id` foreign key despite no table called `role` existing in my production database:

[image: db screenshot]

Baffling :D

### Update 3

Perhaps it's the difference between a sqlite3 database and a postgresql database.

By default, a rails app `config/database.yml` specifies that production database is called `db/production.sqlite3`, i.e. it isn't using a PostgreSQL database, hence why it doesn't give the error about roles not existing.

And according to this Stackoverflow post: [Does SQLite support referential integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213454/does-sqlite-support-referential-integrity)

It appears SQLite3 doesn't guarantee referential integrity :(

Major pain in the butt.

It's a good thing this is only a personal learning project not a work project.

It's also not really feasible to start off with PostgreSQL, you can't just drop and recreate database as easily as you can with SQLite3 and Rails CLI.

I guess the lesson to learn here is to think hard and create the dependant tables first.

Comment: _Do I just rename my create_role migration file to have an earlier timestamp than the create_user migration file?_ -- exactly.

Comment: Renaming, git commit and git push heroku master fixes the first error but then another error saying Book authors (which is of type `User` model) relation does not exists. I think the problem lies somewhere deeper. So based on this result, I don't think renaming migration file is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed all my migrations and got the API running on Heroku server now.

The real answer is: **deploy to Heroku early, don't wait till after finishing development on local machine then deploy.**

Deploy early will identify problems early like my migration discrepancies between SQlite and PostgreSQL.

Additionally, when doing references in migration file, if not using matching model and table names e.g. `author` vs `user`, modify the migration file to use `add_foreign_key` before running the migration.

For example:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.boolean :adult_content
      t.references :author, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Needs to become:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.boolean :adult_content
      t.references :author, index: true # this line changed

      t.timestamps
    end

    # new foreign key specifying correct table name and column
    add_foreign_key :books, :users, column: :author_id 

  end
end
```

Found the new knowledge from this link:

http://sevenseacat.net/2015/02/24/add_foreign_key_gotchas.html

Answer (score 0):

> Do I just rename my create_role migration file to have an earlier timestamp than the create_user migration file? Is that even recommended practice ? :D

Yes it's ok for your case.

**BUT** keep in mind doing so is ok on steps when you are scaffolding your system on very start. Once you have a production database you should be sure that your migrations are run with success before deploy.

So just a tip for future, here the my own best practice of production deploy

1. Dump your production database. You can do it with

   `pg_dump <db_name> > <dump_file>; scp <server>:<path_to_dump_file> ./`

   or https://github.com/sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks

   in case of heroku here is nice [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)
2. Apply it in local environment with

   `psql <db_name> < <dump_file>`
3. Try to run migration
4. If everything go wrong go to step 5 else to step 6
5. Fix migration issues go to step 4
6. Check if migration do not corrupt data, and if it's try to fix migration and start from step 2, otherwise just deploy your code ;)

Comment: A good checklist. However, he already mentioned that the migration worked fine on his local machine.

Comment: The problem is that environment may differ, I think it should not be possible to run even on local machine as `add_references` adds foreign key by default, but it can't be proceed until mentioned tables are exists. Other way is to referece table in separate migrations

Comment: @mixan946 even after renaming my migration file so create role comes before create user table, I get new error saying create book migration file cannot reference author (author is a reference to user table and more importantly, create user migration file already ran before create book migration file, how can it not find the relation?).

Comment: This is the first deploy to Heroku, why would I have a production database, isn't that what I'm trying to create at the moment by running `heroku run rails db:migrate`?

Comment: Your steps also appears to be paradoxical: Step 4 - migration goes wrong, go to step 5, Step 5 fix migration issue, go to step 4 lol, infinite cycle. Step 6, check migration do not corrupt data, fix migration if corrupted...what..?

Answer (score 0):

**Migrating from SQLite to PostgreSQl to deply on heroku.**

I have a situation like this but using tables: attendances, events, and users.

**PG:undifiedTable ERROR: relation users does not exist**

I solved this:

1. Locally I run  **rails db:drop**  - to delete databases locally

   - I had 3 migrations file example
   - 2019_11_07_**20**5648_create_attendace
   - 2019_11_07_**21**5648_create_events
   - 2019_11_07_**22**5648_create_users
2. I change the day in the date in the first 2 files to:

   - 2019_11_07_**22**5648_create_users
   - 2019_11_07_**23**5648_create_events
   - 2019_11_07_**24**5648_create_attendace
3. So they change order and users table is created first, I created the databases and the migration again $**rails db:create
   rails db:migrate** - works locally
4. push to heroku after **committing** - **git push heroku master**
5. **heroku run rails db:migrate**
6. Heroku open  and it's done - Voila  - Finito